# Masonry Images stacked on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

I'm using Masonry to display an image grid;
http://aandagtvooru.nl/grid

But on the first load, all images are stacked on top of each other instead of shown as a Masonry grid.

Used JS:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {

  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('#grid').masonry();
        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({itemSelector: '.grid-item'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, i don't see you've included jquery.js in your page, how masonry is even working?

second, leave only this on your page

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('#grid');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({itemSelector: '.grid-item'});
    });
});
```

all other masonry calls are unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, if I use the code you suggest all items are displayed on the left and the Masonry effect is entirely gone.

Comment: btw, your style and script is outside <head> tag, which is not rite

Comment: I have included jQuery, yes. I see the fiddle is working and I editted the CSS but someone it won't work for me. Full code is here: http://snipsave.com/user/profile/rafaelklein#10665

Comment: just return $(window).load in your script - http://prntscr.com/7ye0vu . in jsfiddle there's no need to write window.load or document.ready, coz they have it in-built here http://prntscr.com/7ye1ii

Comment: I must be crazy or being a complete n00b, but it isn't working, after adding the suggested $(window).load - See code: http://snipsave.com/user/profile/rafaelklein#10665

Comment: I'm going for the "complete n00b" bit. Thank you very much!